# How to disable Visual Studio 2008 localized string replacement in Designer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I use Visual Studio 2008, and in my application I have this line of code in the MainMenu.Designer.cs

```
this.btnSettings.Text = "(5) " + Strings.Settings;
```

Where the Strings.Exit is the following

```
    /// <summary>
    ///   Looks up a localized string similar to Settings.
    /// </summary>
    internal static string Settings {
        get {
            return ResourceManager.GetString("Settings", resourceCulture);
        }
    }
```

but when I rebuild my application, the above line converts automatically to the following

```
this.btnSettings.Text = "(5) Settings";
```

How can I turn this off?

Comment: It's not recommended to make any change like this (or at all) to the designer code in winForms.  You would be better off setting this in the constructor after the `InitializeComponent` method is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have this line of code in the MainMenu.Designer.cs

Do **not** edit the Xxxx.Designer.cs files.  Your changes will be lost when the IDE regenerates the file.  You need to move this statement into the constructor.  You ought to find it back in the MainMenu.cs source file.